# AM PM Time picker Code needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I dont want to use HTML drop down for AM PM time picker in 12 hours format...can any one give me LInk regarding this.I want Jquery/Javascript/CSS based AM PM picker

Comment: Why don't you want to use a dropdown? Also, AM vs. PM could be a radio button as well. I would highly suggest starting with native form variables and then modifying them in order to keep your page as accessible as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that does what you want, though tbthorpe is right, it might be good to make the two spans I use into radio buttons, and style those so they work the same as my solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/PPQQ8/

What you could do is, have radio buttons with a class on it, and use jQuery to hide those and replace them with the clickable spans which actually trigger the radio button clicks. Probably a better solution for accessibility.

Comment: Actuly i need a date picker which contains the hour pattern with AM PM.......yOur example is good but it will be highly appreciable if you give a fiddle with hour and minutes

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more robust time picker than just AM/PM - it's a jQuery plugin.  Presumably, you could pare down the js/css and have it just let you pick am or pm.

http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

I found this trying to find a decent time picker which supports US AM/PM style and doesn't use a drop down. The best tool for me was anytime. http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

example code (assuming you have loaded jQuery and the AnyTime script)

```
$("#field2").AnyTime_picker( {
    format: "%h:%i %p",
    labelTitle: "Time",
    labelHour: "Hour",
    labelMinute: "Minute"
} );
```

supporting html

```
<input type="text" id="field2" value="" readonly="">
```

Example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/brianlmerritt/Lzn7fnnw/2/

And it looks like this...

[image]